# How to get a exact number from a String in sql server?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How to get Order Numbers(189,190) from following TrigParams field in SQL server 2014 Database.

TrigParams

```
{"OWLSObjKey":{"key":"OWLSObjKey","value":"189","type":null},"OWLSObjType":{"key":"OWLSObjType","value":"17","type":null},"ObjKey":{"key":"ObjKey","value":"189","type":null},"ObjType":{"key":"ObjType","value":"17","type":null}}
{"OWLSObjKey":{"key":"OWLSObjKey","value":"190","type":null},"OWLSObjType":{"key":"OWLSObjType","value":"17","type":null},"ObjKey":{"key":"ObjKey","value":"190","type":null},"ObjType":{"key":"ObjType","value":"17","type":null}}
```

Comment: SQL Server Version? What have you tried?

Comment: That's not a good question and would force people to guess. What's the table's schema and what's the server version? Is this string the content of a single field or the contents of two rows? SQL Server 2016 and later support JSON which means you could use `JSON_VALUE` to retrieve the data. If that string is a *single* value though, it's invalid JSON

Comment: How do you intend to use those values? Return them in results? Join them with other data? You may have to use different JSON functions in each case

Comment: Hi this is from SQL Server 2014 Database.This field related to SAP B1 OWLS table.I need to get this value to join ORDR table(Order Details) by Primary Key of DocEntry

Answer (score 1):

You see from the other answers, that SQL-Server 2016+ with broad JSON support would be of great help. But without you are not lost. You can use string methods:

*credits to Panagiotis Kanavos for the MCVE*

```
declare @table table (trigparams nvarchar(2000))

insert into @table 
values
('{"OWLSObjKey":{"key":"OWLSObjKey","value":"189","type":null},"OWLSObjType":{"key":"OWLSObjType","value":"17","type":null},"ObjKey":{"key":"ObjKey","value":"189","type":null},"ObjType":{"key":"ObjType","value":"17","type":null}}'),
('{"OWLSObjKey":{"key":"OWLSObjKey","value":"190","type":null},"OWLSObjType":{"key":"OWLSObjType","value":"17","type":null},"ObjKey":{"key":"ObjKey","value":"190","type":null},"ObjType":{"key":"ObjType","value":"17","type":null}}')
```

--This is the query

```
select LEFT(CutOff,CHARINDEX('"',CutOff)-1)
from @table t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT STUFF(t.trigparams,1,CHARINDEX('"value":"',t.trigparams)+8,'')) A(CutOff);
```

The idea in short:

Within the `APPLY` we will use `STUFF()` to write *nothing* over the first characters up to the number you are looking for (after the first occurance of `"value":"`. This is returned as Column *CutOff*. We can now use `LEFT()` to pick the number only.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't specify the server version, the table schema or whether the string represents a single value or the contents of two separate rows.

I'll just *assume* it's SQL Server 2016 which supports JSON and the text comes from two separate rows. I'll also *assume* the query only needs to return the data as single value.

In this case a simple call to `JSON_VALUE('$.OWLSObjKey.value')` will return the data. [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns a single value from a well-formed JSON string :

```
declare @table table (trigparams nvarchar(2000))

insert into @table 
values
('{"OWLSObjKey":{"key":"OWLSObjKey","value":"189","type":null},"OWLSObjType":{"key":"OWLSObjType","value":"17","type":null},"ObjKey":{"key":"ObjKey","value":"189","type":null},"ObjType":{"key":"ObjType","value":"17","type":null}}'),
('{"OWLSObjKey":{"key":"OWLSObjKey","value":"190","type":null},"OWLSObjType":{"key":"OWLSObjType","value":"17","type":null},"ObjKey":{"key":"ObjKey","value":"190","type":null},"ObjType":{"key":"ObjType","value":"17","type":null}}')

select JSON_VALUE(trigparams,'$.OWLSObjKey.value') As SomeKey
from @table
```

This returns :

```
SomeKey 
189 
190
```

Comment: Hi this is from SQL Server 2014 Database.This field related to SAP B1 OWLS table.I need to get this value to join ORDR table(Order Details) by Primary Key of DocEntry.

Answer (score -1):

***Assuming*** you're using SQL Server 2016+, use `OPENJSON`:

```
SELECT O.OrderNumber
FROM (VALUES('{"OWLSObjKey":{"key":"OWLSObjKey","value":"189","type":null},"OWLSObjType":{"key":"OWLSObjType","value":"17","type":null},"ObjKey":{"key":"ObjKey","value":"189","type":null},"ObjType":{"key":"ObjType","value":"17","type":null}}'),
            ('{"OWLSObjKey":{"key":"OWLSObjKey","value":"190","type":null},"OWLSObjType":{"key":"OWLSObjType","value":"17","type":null},"ObjKey":{"key":"ObjKey","value":"190","type":null},"ObjType":{"key":"ObjType","value":"17","type":null}}')) V(TrigParams)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.TrigParams) WITH (OWLSObjKey nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) OK
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OK.OWLSObjKey) WITH (OrderNumber int '$.value') O;
```

If not, then SQL Server is not your friend for this without using a CLR Function. If you can't use CLR, then I would suggest using a different tool to read the JSON value.

Comment: Would be interesting to hear why this had a Downvote. Why/how can this be improved?

Comment: Hmmm, clearly the voter feels silence is golden. Shame.